# Get all services with PackageInfo

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

I have a problem with an app of mine. I use this code to uninstall a package, fired from a Service:

```
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+packageName);
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
uninstallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

The problem is, I've heard from someone who is using this app that there is no uninstall dialog opening on a Sony Xperia Z. It works on my Samsung phones, one with Touchwiz and one with Cyanogenmod and also on my Nexus 7.

I tried to change the intent to:

```
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
```

This also works on my devices but not his. Anyone who has an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("com.the.package",
getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkUri.getPath(), 0).packageName,null));
startActivity(deleteIntent);
```

hope it helps